# Understanding different ways of using accessors

Tags: c#, properties

For an object sellprint declared as static in the class

```
private static string sellprint  = "";

public string Sellprint
{
    get { return sellprint; }            
}
public void SetSellprint(string x)
{
      sellprint = x;
}
```

How is this 
different from

```
public string Sellprint
{
    get; set;
}
```

internally.

I could not find any examples of code 1 on msdn. what does it translate into?

Comment: When you say you were getting the "cannot convert object of type Prints to object of type Prints" error, what was the code being used? The functionality really isn't different, assuming that sellprint is being declared as a class property somewhere.

Comment: Well per se, i only have to use sellprint inside of the class within its methods , i never really have to expose it to an outside class. Also, The editor which i am using serialises the whole code.

Comment: I was just putting sellprint inside a Prints LinkedList, which is also private static, in a method inside the same class. I havent gotten that error yet, but i would like to know why i was getting it , since cant be sure if the issue has been resolved yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler creates a *getter* method for your property in the first code that returns the value of `sellprint` field because you implement only the *getter* method.In the second code, both *getter* and *setter* methods creating by compiler and also the *backing-field*.That's the difference.

You can verify that using [`ILDASM.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

First, consider this code:

```
class Foo
{
    private string _value;

    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }

    public void SetValue(string str)
    {
        _value = str;
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see there is only one method generated by compiler which is `get_Value`.

If we change it like this and make the `Value` an *auto-implemented* property:

```
class Foo
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

You can see that compiler creates both *getter* (`get_Value`) and *setter* (`set_Value`) method and also create a `private` backing field for the property.

There is no *pros* or *cons* about the functionality except in the second code you are doing the same work with *less* code.

Comment: so since the compiler does not generate a setter, if we have an object of class Foo, lets say abc, in first code, i have to use abc.SetValue("Some text"); to change the text in value vs the second code, where i use abc.Value = "Some text" ?

Comment: @novice in the first example, yes

Answer (score 0):

1) should not work because there is no sellprint - assuming you have a field named sellprint and just forgot in your code snippet, you provide a get accessors and a method instead of the set accessors, which is kinda strange.

2) will create the field required automatically (and will not tell you the name, so you cannot accidentally use it)

There is not difference between those two though.